# How to hide spring batch run parameters after completion

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch application where user provides the job run parameters via command line arguments.Every thing is fine,but after job completion I could see parameters the in the log.I don't want to be printed in the log is there any way to hide them.

```
[FloJob :[name="MasterToolJob"]] completed with following job paramaters ....
```

Comment: Do you want to hide in log only or database?

Comment: In the Log only and any way i am not putting them in the database

Comment: If so, is that okay for you if you set WARN with log4j for Spring batch. For example <logger name="org.springframework.batch">
 <level value="WARN" />
 <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</logger>

Comment: Thanks I will make changes.

Comment: Finally i applied this and it worked.`<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
   <version>${spring-batch-core.version}</version>
   <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
  </dependency>`

Comment: It's great. Please mark as Answer so people can know.